# How to slice using true colors?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

Most of the time when PSD's are slicers I keep getting slicers giving me the modified colors
for the web. I want to know how to slice using true colors for the web.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact colors use photoshop to slice the psd.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a solid color just press "i" in photoshop, click on that color. And at bottom that color's hex-decimal vlaue will display. Just copy that value and paste it in CSS as BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff.

If it is a gradient copy that whole layer, then merge it. Resize canvas 1px then trim it. And save it as **example.png**.

Then in CSS:

```
#id { background: url("example.png") repeat; }
```

That all.